# Collapse a view on scroll (AirBnB explore like)

Tags: android, android-animation, android-coordinatorlayout

In fact there are two questions in that question.

1) I would like to expand/collapse a view when the user scroll with an animation similar to the AirBnB app (when the search filters appear).
I assumed that they were using a CoordinatorLayout with a CollapsingToolbar but I could not reproduce their animation. I guess they are using CoordinatorLayout.Behavior to achieve this result but I was not able to use it well. Can someone confirm that they use a Coordinator and Coordinator behavior to achieve that smooth animation ?

2) Moreover my problem is that my view hierachy is not exactly the same.[image: Expanded search][image: Collapsed search]

My Tab is above the layout I would like to collapse/expand. Is it still possible to do it with a CoordinatorLayout by using CoordinatorLayout.Behavior ?

For information I achieved to implement a collapse/expand animation when the user clicks the GO button or the collapsed search field but it's not what I had in mind.

**EDIT :**

I succeeded in my attempt to have TabLayout above the collapsing toolbar by putting it and the coordinator layout in a LinearLayout.

I've created a layout to have the behaviour I wanted

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Search" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Popular" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Favorites" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
                    app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/summarized_search_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/background_blue_light_rounded"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:padding="12dp"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="none">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="20dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:src="@drawable/menu_search" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/summarized_search_text"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginStart="12dp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/extended_search_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="1">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/background_blue_light_rounded"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:padding="12dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="20dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:src="@drawable/menu_profile" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginStart="12dp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/background_blue_light_rounded"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:padding="12dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="20dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:src="@drawable/menu_calendar" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginStart="12dp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/background_blue_light_rounded"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:padding="12dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="20dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:src="@drawable/menu_poi" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginStart="12dp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/background_blue_light_rounded"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:padding="12dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="20dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:src="@drawable/menu_poi" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginStart="12dp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/validation_button"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="end"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:text="GO" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:contentPadding="16dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
                    android:text="@string/lorem"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

But I'm not really happy with my toolbar having a visibility set to invisible just to have a part of the view remaining when my collapsing toolbar is collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same by putting your non collapsing field (search view) in between the TabLayout and CoordinatorLayout. I've achieved the same like that. So whatever view you are trying to collapse to 0 should be inside the CollapsingToolbalLayout. Let me know if you need more info..

PS: Were you able to successfully replicate the entire behaviour ?